# How to add a firestore reference type field in php?

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add data with a reference field type to my collection. How to code this within PHP?

I added:

```
$db = new FirestoreClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);

$addedDocRef = $db->collection('locations')->newDocument();
$addedDocRef->set([
    'decisionRef' => $db->document('decisions/' . $ID),
    'formattedAddress' => $formattedAddress,
    'point' => [
        'geohash' => $geohash,
        'geopoint' => new GeoPoint($lat,$lng)
    ]
]);
```

I expected to see a reference type field in my document, but I got this error:

> Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ValidationException: Error rendering 'projects/{project=*}/databases/{database=*}': expected binding ...

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set a $decisionRef outside the set([...]) array

`$decisionRef = $db->document('decisions/' . $ID)`